# CKFinder gem for ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

I installed the gem ckeditor by tsechingho. But i cant use the edeitor to upload any image on the editor.

Is there any way i can add uplaod images using CKFinder?

Answer (score 1):

[CKEditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) gem doesn't use CKFinder but allows file/image uploads through a custom file browser.

On the other hand, if you have to use CKFinder, you will need to implement a Rails backend (possibly as an engine like the aforementioned gem). Unfortunately, [server side integration docs](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Server_Side_Integration) exist only for v2.